# How to keep Chrome open when opened using Selenium WebDriver in Mac

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to open Chrome and load a webpage using Selenium C# WebDriver. The issue I am having is, Chrome opens and loads the page and closes right away.

Here is my code:

```
//I copied the chromedriver.exe to my project directory
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory))
{
    try
    {
        //Maximize the browser
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
    catch (TimeoutException te) {
        string y = te.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception ce) {
        string k = ce.Message;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to resolve it would be helpful.

Comment: What error are you getting??

Comment: Do you want to perform operations on the opened browser as part of your script? If yes, then just use the `driver`

Comment: There is no error in the console. Yes i would like to use the opened page to do operation but I can't do it if the browser is not open anymore.

Comment: Make sure to add all your operation in the`try` block in your code.

Comment: That's the only code I have for now but the browser isn't staying open. I am running this test of a Mac if that help with finding a solution.

Comment: you are swallowing the exception

Comment: Can you please clarify @CoreyGoldberg? What should I do?